# Is it possible to have HTML5 color input value transparent?

Tags: html

Putting any value other than HEX (#ffffff) gives a console error. But I was wondering if user wanted no color and transparent instead.

I know the below syntax not going to work anyway. But is there any way that can achieve transparent value.

```
<input type='color' value='transparent'/>
```

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#rules-for-serializing-simple-color-values

Comment: There's additional discussion here: https://github.com/w3c/html/issues/1422

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's currently possible to set a transparent value using a native HTML color input:

> Note: Setting the value to anything that isn't a valid, fully-opaque, RGB color in hexadecimal notation will result in the value being set to #000000. In particular, you can't use CSS's standardized color names, or any CSS function syntax, to set the value.
>
> This makes sense when you keep in mind that HTML and CSS are separate languages and specifications. In addition, colors with an alpha channel are not supported; specifying a color in 9-character hexadecimal notation (e.g. #009900aa) will also result in the color being set to #000000.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#value

A potential solution could be using a library like [Pickr.js](https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr).

Answer (score -7):

```html
<div style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
   <div>
      Text added.
   </div>
</div>
```

Currently there is no direct transparent background support for HTML5. I would suggest CSS

link here: [CSS Background Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422949/css-background-opacity)

Comment: You are not answering the question.