# How to Insert Blur Background Image in the content without disturbing the text in the content?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm giving the background here then
declaring the content in the next div

```
back{
    background-image: link
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    opacity:0.25
}
```

When i tried this whole page gets the opacity property. i want only the opacity property to be inherited to the background image not to the content elements.

Comment: [This has already been answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422949/css-background-opacity)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to put image in one div and text in other div then place the content using position property on image.