# CSS Opacity atop Image Overlay

Tags: css, uikit

I am seeking help correcting the opacity on a class. Please pardon my not having shown the work for the many approaches I have tried.

Following is a demo on codepen:
[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/evanesoteric/pen/PoYOaVb)

```
.intro .uk-overlay-primary {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.intro .intro-title {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The 'intro-title' class is inheriting the opacity of the 'ul-overlay' class. How can I resolve this, forcing the 'intro-title' opacity to be 1, atop of the overlay class?

Comment: I believe this is similar to this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422949/css-background-opacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented this is somehow similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422949/css-background-opacity). For the solution, you can try [this](https://codepen.io/yorsaquing/pen/XWrzOME). I changed the structure if its okay to you and made the overlay `position: absolute`

```
.intro .uk-overlay-primary {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(326deg, #80009F 0%, #643097 98%);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

There are other ways to get this result but I choose to use this approach to have minor changes on your code.

For better understanding, as mentioned in [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)

> opacity applies to the element as a whole, including its contents,
>   even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, the
>   element and its children all have the same opacity relative to the
>   element's background, even if they have different opacities relative
>   to one another.

Comment: Hi Yor, thank you very much for having taken the time. I very much appreciate this solution as well as the links provided. Most excellent, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple. You need to use the background opacity rather than style `opacity`. Change the following css and it should work fine :)

```
.intro .uk-overlay-primary 
{
    background-image: linear-gradient(326deg, #80009F50 0%, #64309750 98%);
}
```