# Change background image opacity on hover in angular and scss

Tags: angular, sass, hover, background-image, opacity

i have angular component with dynamic background-image fetched from server:

```
  <div
    class="picture"
    [style.background-image]="'url(' + this.category.photo + ')'"
  >
    <div class="seeDetails">
        join group
      <button>see details</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

After putting mouse over .picture class .seeDetails appear with text and button inside it, in CSS it looks like this:

```
.picture {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.seeDetails {
  display: none;
}

.picture:hover {
opacity:0.2;
  .seeDetails {
    display: block;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
  }

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

i want to set background image opacity to 0.2 after hover, but it also set text and button opacity to 0.2.

I have read about solution with pseudoelement ::before https://coder-coder.com/background-image-opacity/ but i can't figure out how to use it in this case with :hover.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I give text or an image a transparent background using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/how-do-i-give-text-or-an-image-a-transparent-background-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(There is [a little bit simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18985783/397872) with `::before`/`::after`, but you would have to move the dynamic background url to css to make it work.)

You should have:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="background" [style.background-image]="'url(' + this.category.photo + ')'">
    </div>
    <div class="seeDetails">
        join group
      <button>see details</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;

  > div.background {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  &:hover > div.background {
     opacity: 0.2;
  }

  > div.seeDetails {
    display: block;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
  }
}
```

Note: `inset` does not work everywhere. You should create a mixin:

```css
@mixin inset($size: 0) {
    inset: $size;
    top: $size;
    left: $size;
    right: $size;
    bottom: $size;
}
```

And use it as:

```css
div.container {
  // ...

  > div.background {
    position: absolute;
    @include inset(0 !important);
    background-size: cover;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Comment: this works! but now fade in animation stopped working